# Equivalence class is a group - request for proof-verification.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Here's a request for proof-verification - thank you.

> Show that the set
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} & = \{a + n \mathbb{Z}\;|\; a \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
> & = \{n\mathbb{Z}, 1 + n\mathbb{Z}, \dots, (n-1) + n\mathbb{Z}\}.
> \end{align*}
>   $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a group, with group operation
>   $$(a + n\mathbb{Z}) + (b + n\mathbb{Z}) : = (a+b) + n \mathbb{Z}$$

First we show Equivalence class are well defined. Consider $a_1, a_2 \in [a], b \in [b]$. And we show $[a_1 + b] = [a_2 + b]$.

$a_1, a_2 \in [a]$ says
$$a_1,a_2 = a + n\mathbb{Z} \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
By definition of group operation,

\begin{align*}
a_1 + b & = \{a + n \mathbb{Z}\;|\; a \in \mathbb{Z}\} + \{b + n \mathbb{Z}\;|\; b \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
& = a_2 + b.
\end{align*}

Then we show that this is a group.

- Identity: [0]
- Associativity: $([a] + [b]) + [c] = [a] + ([b] + [c])$ by associativity of addition.
- Closure: $[a]+[b] = [a+b] \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$
- Inverse: $\forall [a] \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \exists [a^{-1}] \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $[a] + [a^{-1}] = [0]$ by letting $[a^{-1}] = [n - a]$, hence $[a] + [a^{-1}] = [a] + [n - a] = [0].$

Comment: That is nice to know...

Comment: Sounds like I messed up @Tunococ? :-P

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @Tunococ It's tagged as proof-verification, so my pyschic powers tell me that it's a question about whether the proof is valid or not. But it would be nice if that was actually stated in the question.

Comment: hmm, thanks @T.Bongers, I added.

Comment: @T.Bongers Oh. It's in one of the tags! I think I can help out now. The equation $a_1 + b = a_2 + b$ is not quite right, but what was proved later was right: $[a_1 + b] = [a_2 + b]$. I am not sure why you need it though. I would just add a proof that $+$ is well-defined in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. And the last line, I think you mean $[a] + [b] = [a + b]$.

Comment: Don't you want to say a word or two about inverses?

Comment: I see, that is very helpful, thank you very mucy @Tunococ

Comment: Oh yes, I thank you @GerryMyerson